# How to open a web page in the background?

Tags: browser, background, window, hide

I use the following code to visit a web page from the background,

```
HINSTANCE fan=ShellExecuteA(NULL,"open","http://www.yahoo.com",NULL,NULL,SW_HIDE);
```

but the browser is not hidden.

Any suggestions?

Comment: looks like you are making something illegal.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to do this. It's up to the browser whether a new window/tab is focused or not.